# mono for android 4.2.6 offline installer

Tags: android

I'm looking on the internet for mono for android offline installer. Does any one have a link to mentioned software (mono for android 4.2.6. offline)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you mean mono platform runtime. download and install mono for android and then go to "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Novell\platforms" for x64 or "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Novell\platforms" for x86 and choose platform and direcotry. there is Mono.Android.Platform.apk file



but is better to link assembly with your apk.



direct link to download 2.4.6: http://download.xamarin.com/MonoforAndroid/Windows/mono-android-4.2.6.103999197.msi

Comment: No, I have a offline computer and need link like answered in the thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118684/mono-for-android-offline-installer

Comment: ok. I add direct link...

Answer (score 4):

Direct download link for Mono For Android 4.6.08007

http://download.xamarin.com/MonoforAndroid/Windows/mono-android-4.6.08007.msi

If you want latest version, download Xamarin installer, run it, start download, go to

```
[SYSTEM DRIVE]:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\downloads
```

and open "InstallationManifest.xml"... then grab all urls and cancel download.

Regards

Comment: Can you share direct link for v+8? I tired everything, but no success

Answer (score 3):

Direct Download link For Mono For Android 4.6.00049 (154 MB)

Link.:

https://download.xamarin.com/MonoforAndroid/Windows/mono-android-4.6.00049.msi

Enjoy..